# Input file unable to be read. Console showing "Unable to open file : InFile.tx"

Tags: c++, file

I am trying to get an input file to be opened and read, but the console is unable to read the file named "InFile.txt" and saying "Unable to open file : InFile.tx". I am using eclipse c++ IDE and have the InFile.txt and OFile.txt saved alongside the main.cpp.

```
      int main() {

                   string infile, outfile;

               readFilenames(infile,outfile);

               ifstream file;
               file.open(infile.c_str());

                ...
                
                void readFilenames(string &infile, string &outfile)

         {

           cout<<"What input file would you like to use? ";

           getline(cin,infile);

           infile = infile.substr(0,infile.length()-1);

           cout<<"What output file would you like to use? ";

           getline(cin,outfile);

           outfile = outfile.substr(0,outfile.length()-1);
          

           }
```

Comment: Look at the filename `InFilke.tx`. Doesn't it miss a character at the end? The [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function does *not* include the newline, which you should have known if you read anything about it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so what do i have to change in order to make the file be read entirely?

Comment: Why are you doing those `substr` calls? Who told you to do them? What was their reason? You might want to think about them for a while.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I thought that might fix the problem, just a shot in the dark no real reason. Without the substr calls the file was still not being read.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude OOHHHHH IM DUMB. thank you, i got it